# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 134.53.148.193:21

Tags: linux, ftp

I am using remote ftp in atom and I am trying to connect to a remote Linux server(its a .edu). I am pretty sure I am entering in all of the information correctly, but I keep getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 134.53.148.193:21

I've watched a couple of videos, but I can't figure out what they are doing differently.

```
"protocol": "ftp",
"host": "servername.edu",
"port": 21,
"user": "username@servername.edu",
"promptForPass": true,
"remote": "/",
"local": "",
"secure": false,
"secureOptions": null,
"connTimeout": 10000,
"pasvTimeout": 10000,
"keepalive": 10000,
"watch": [],
"watchTimeout": 500
```

Answer (score 0):

just a guess: It's wise to allow only secure connections to an FTP-Server. Maybe they configured the server accordingly and you should try a secure connection. (set option secure to implicit or control)

if available try SFTP via Port 22 as well.

[edit] seems there is nothing available on Port 21 on this IP - it might be behind a firewall or running on a different Port. Universities can be quite strict about such things.